# The number of custom close reasons

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I think we need one more custom closing reason in the off-topic closing dialog box.

1. Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in theoretical computer science. For more information about the scope, please see help center. Your question might be suitable for Computer Science which has a broader scope.
2. Our site policy prohibits simultaneous crossposting: it duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Crossposting is permitted after a week has passed without a satisfying answer elsewhere. When crossposting please summarize the relevant discussions from other sites in your question and link between the copies in both directions.
3. Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also our question checklist.
4. Questions about the general correctness of unpublished preprints and solutions of major open problems are off-topic. For more information, see our policy for questions about preprints.

Can the number of our custom closing reasons be increased from 3 to 4?

Comment: plz be specific, which one is the new one?